# Jupyternotebook Display issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook

all I am new to data science and machine learning, and I currently working on an EDA project with NYC yellow taxi datasets. I have a Conda env and am working with Juppyternotebooks. When I use the bellow command I expected a graph to display but only get AxesSubplot:. I am assuming the constriction of the plot happens correctly but I am missing something to display correctly can you please advise. I do have imports for matplotlib, pandas, missingno and some others.

```
msno.matrix(data_taxi_march)
<AxesSubplot:>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `;` to end of line or use `%matplotlib inline` at begging of the cell.